# Django admin listview Customize Column Name

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Ok so I have a custom django admin built from a Author Model:

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Author Admin
    """
    form = AuthorForm

    list_display = ['profile_photo', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'title']
    search_fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'title', 'credential']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'title')}

    def profile_photo(self, obj) :
        return '<img src="%s" title="%s" />' % (resize_image(obj.photo, '100x100'), obj.title)

    profile_photo.allow_tags = True
```

But in the django admin listview the column title for the custom column does not have proper capitalization.
[image: capitalization matters dammit!]

Does anyone know how to override the column headers that are built from custom function's names?

I've tried:

```
def my_function(self, obj) :
    """My Custom Title"""
    ...
```

and

```
def my_function(self, obj) :
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u"My Custom Title")
```

Comment: From what module are you importing `resize_image` function?

Comment: oh man this is like 10 years old, probably sorl thumbnail? @artu-hnrq

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Use:

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    …
    def my_function(self, obj) :
        """My Custom Title"""
    …
    my_function.short_description = 'This is the Column Name'
```

It's buried in the [admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display). `short_description`, specifically, is barely mentioned under the discussion of `list_display` (more by example than actually called out). The other items like this are similiarly buried in the admin docs, but here's a summary:

- `short_description`: the column title to use (string)
- `allow_tags`: what the name says... let's you use HTML (`True` or `False`)
- `admin_order_field`: a field on the model to order this column by (string, field name)
- `boolean`: indicates the return value is boolean and signals the admin to use the nice graphic green check/red X (`True` or `False`)

Comment: works great, is there some page in the docs where I could read more about this and other features like it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this destroys the possibility to sort by this column

Comment: @cxxl I found [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#:~:text=Usually%2C%20elements%20of%20list_display%20that%20aren%E2%80%99t%20actual%20database%20fields%20can%E2%80%99t%20be%20used%20in%20sorting%20(because%20Django%20does%20all%20the%20sorting%20at%20the%20database%20level).)

Answer (score 11):

Starting from **Django 3.2** you can use the `display` decorator. It has the attribute `description` for changing the name of the column:

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['profile_photo', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'title']

    @admin.display(description='Profile Photo')
    def profile_photo(self, obj) :
        return '<img src="%s" title="%s" />' % (resize_image(obj.photo, '100x100'), obj.title)
```

For more info about the `display` decorator see [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#the-display-decorator)

Answer (score 1):

Inside your models.py model class you can simply do as follows for (usually) any field:

```
your_field = models.CharField(max_length=123456789, verbose_name="WOWYWOWY!!!")
```

Comment: Completely irrelevant answer, renaming a column in admin panel has nothing to do with verbose_name in models

Comment: Have you actually tried this before down voting the answer? This offers an alternative solution to the original question. Please check first and revisit.

Comment: Yes bro, I have tried it yesterday & is not working this way.

Comment: That's really odd. I've just double checked it and it works fine. Are you sure you did the migrations after changing it? 

In my models.py I have 
`field_name = models.CharField(...., verbose_name='Whatever')` 
and in my admin.py I have the fields registered as needed with 
`list_display=['field_name',...]`.

And that does exactly what I explained above. I am on Django 3.2.

Comment: I am using django 3.2 myself on python3.6 and yes i applied migrations but it didnt show the title as specified in verbose_name. `def project_logo_ftn(self, obj):
        return format_html('<img src="{}" width="auto" height="200px" />'.format(obj.project_logo.url)) project_logo_ftn.short_description = 'Project Logo'`
I used this method to display the image and set the name to project Logo in admin

Comment: may be your method work for non image fields only.

Comment: @saadatali this is what I am starting to think as well. Could be that this works only on character like fields maybe. Image (and other type) fields might not have the property 'verbose_name' available. That would explain it.

Comment: it works with character like fields

Comment: It also works with Integer fields (Django 4.2). But all letters in the verbose_name are shown capitalized.