# Make change_list column editable AND change its name without changing the Model class field label

Tags: django, django-admin

I am new to Django and am facing some issues with customizing a `change_list`. I am trying to make a changelist column editable, AND change the column's display name. I managed to change the display name of the column by using a callable that returns the model field value, setting its `short_description` property to the new column name and then adding the callable to the `list_display`, which works fine. I then add the callable to the `list_editable`, but then the editable field cannot get resolved. I get the error

> The value of 'list_editable[0]' refers to 'get_instruction_date',
>   which is not an attribute of 'employee.Onboarding'.

Is there a way to get this working (make column editable **AND** changing its display name/label) **WITHOUT** having to change the Model class itself? The model is being used elsewhere and field labels are set to meet that use case.

EDIT:
So, I currently set the column name as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9708520/3818185), as such:

`def get_instruction_date(self, obj):
    return obj.instruction_date
get_instruction_date.short_description = 'Appointment'
list_display = ('get_instruction_date', 'instruction_done',...)`

which works fine, but prevents me to make the column editable by adding it to the `list_editable` list in the respective admin class.

`list_editable = ('get_instruction_date', 'instruction_done')` throws the error I printed above.

Comment: please share appropriate code so it easy to understand.

Comment: @DevangHingu I've updated the question with additional info.