# Django: change column headers in Admin ListView without losing sortability

Tags: python, django, listview

I just want to change the column header in Django' Admin ListView.

There is already an answer: [Django admin listview Customize Column Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708455/django-admin-listview-customize-column-name), but this solution (define a function and set `.short_description` on it) comes at the cost of no longer being able to sort by the column in question.

I cannot find any other solution.  It seems to simple a wish that I cannot believe it cannot be done.

Comment: .admin_order_field

Comment: Yeah, I found that out as well! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ac2001 writes, the solution is the [`admin_order_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).